# Missing asn1.h on httpd build from source

Tags: apache, openssl

i have been trying to build `httpd-2.4.43` from source and i included `OpenSSL-fips-2.0.16`.

However, i encountered an error during build process of httpd. see below;

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/support'
/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/openssl-fips-2.0.16/include  -g -O2 -pthread      -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE   \
      -I. -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/os/unix -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/include -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/srclib/apr/include -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/srclib/apr-util/include -I/usr/local/include -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/aaa -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/cache -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/core -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/database -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/filters -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/ldap -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/server -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/loggers -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/lua -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/proxy -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/http2 -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/session -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/ssl -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/test -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/server -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/md -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/arch/unix -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/dav/main -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/generators -I/root/httpd/httpd-2.4.43/modules/mappers  -prefer-non-pic -static -c ab.c && touch ab.lo
In file included from ab.c:161:0:
/opt/openssl-fips-2.0.16/include/openssl/rsa.h:62:26: fatal error: openssl/asn1.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/asn1.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [ab.lo] Error 1
```

Above error message points to missing `asn1.h`.

I do not know where to find it. Maybe there is a missing procedure on building OpenSSL from source? 
I feel i miss something when building `OpenSSL` from source.

Please do point me to the right direction for this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install OpenSSL development package, which is available in standard repositories of all modern Linux distributions.

Install OpenSSL development package on Debian, Ubuntu or their derivatives:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

To install OpenSSL development package on Fedora, CentOS or RHEL:

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it. Apprently, when i search for resources, i was finding the asn1.h problem not knowing that rsa.h part which includes asn1.h.

So it was found out that this was due to the *ssl-devel dependencies while building openssl.

So please install the *ssl-devel in your build envionrment
`openssl-devel` for RHEL/Fedora
`libssl-devel` for Debian

Then rebuild `OpenSSL` then `httpd`